# add column in Table if its not exists in sqlite

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I want to add one extra column in my table.
Can anybody tell me how to add column in Table if its not exists in sqlite updating whole sqlite database ?

```
if COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('Customers'),'CLable','Text') is null 
    begin 
        alter table Customers add CLable varchar(50) not null 
    end
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

try like this ,by using ALTER command you can achieve this one ,

```
ALTER TABLE Name ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: How this answer is acceptable? There is nothing written about how to check the existence of column.

Comment: This answer works, but still produces an error if the column already exists (in which case it does nothing). If the column doesn't exist, this statement will add it

Answer (score 4):

Don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment above, but ...

```
ALTER TABLE Name ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0
```

will generate an error (not SQLITE_OK) in the prepare() step -- so just ignore it and don't do the step():

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [self.sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite you can not check the existence of a column using `IF NOT EXISTS` ...

You could simply check for `SELECT col from TABLE` If it returns error then column doesn't exists.

or you can use a flag in app delegate like

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isColumnAdded"]) {

    //call the query like ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN columnName TEXT;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isColumnAdded"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
}
```